# GITLAB ci and Ansible Tower-cli extra vars

Tags: ansible, gitlab

I am trying to run a job template from a Tower server using extra vars as part of a Gitlab Pipeline.

The extra var that I am trying to pass to the playbook is derived from a file lookup and this is working fine. I am able to use artifacts to set an environment variable that persist to the deploy stage.

I am hitting a snag when trying to pass this variable via tower-cli -e and I hope that someone has done something similar.

My (very developmental) gitlab-ci file is this, I've "hard coded" a version number to test:

```
stages:          
  - build
  - deploy
build-job:       
  stage: build
  tags:
    - test1
  before_script:
    - pwd
  script:
    - export VERSION=235.5.12
    - export VER=$VERSION
    - echo "BUILD_VERSION=235.5.12" >> build.env
    - echo $VER
    - mkdir ../.$VER
    - mv ../.$VER ../$VER
  artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv: build.env
deploy-job:
  stage: deploy
  tags:
    - test1
  script:
    - echo $BUILD_VERSION
    - APP_VER=$BUILD_VERSION
    - echo "$APP_VER = is the variable we want"
    - tower-cli job launch -J 762 -e "version=$APP_VER" # what is the correct syntax?
  needs:
    job: build-job
    artifacts: true
```

I have tried this with -e "version={{ lookup('env', 'APP_VER') }}"

but the pipeline fails with:

```
echo "$APP_VER = is the variable we want"
235.5.12 = is the variable we want
tower-cli job launch -J 762 -e "version={{ lookup('env', 'APP_VER') }}"
Error: failed to parse some of the extra variables.
variables: 
version={{ lookup('env', 'APP_VER') }}
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:01
**ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1***
```